# Wordpress Twenty Eleven searchform.php vulnerability

Tags: php, wordpress, eval

My Wordpress Twenty Eleven searchform.php got hacked and created evil `eval(base64_decode("Hi I have hacked your site. Haha"))`
I quickly found this out from my Nginx access log, found the script as it was executing via HTTP protocol, then put an exit at the first line which now stopped the script generating mass spam mails from my server.

My question is how can this happen initially? Did the hacker posted some POST or GET variables via the form in `searchform.php` knowing that at some stage it would be executed with `eval()` function so included something like `fopen` and `fwrite` as part of the string?

If so, where is this `eval()` located and how does it get processed?

My `searchform.php` got completely rewritten

Any ideas guys?

Comment: How do you know that `searchform.php` was the point of access?

Comment: Because I checked my Nginx access log and it was accessing that file initially

Comment: It would be useful to see the log entries. That is pretty much necessary to answer this, "My question is how can this happen initially? Did the hacker posted some POST or GET variables via the form in searchform.php..."

Answer (score 1):

The last and updated version of the theme is TwentyTwelve : 
http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve

About the vulnerability of your website, do the authorizations of folders are good or you have put everything in 777?

check this link : http://www.orangecopper.com/blog/recommended-file-and-folder-permissions-for-your-wordpress-blog-installation/